# service already declared in puppet

Tags: puppet

I created a ntp module where I started a service and then I want to stop it. I wrote the entire code in a single `ntp.pp` file. Did writing the code in a single file create this problem?

My code is:

```
package { 'ntp': ensure => installed }

service { 'ntp-run':
  name    => 'ntpd',
  ensure  => running,
  require => Package['ntp'],
}

file { '/tmp/classtest': ensure => file }

file { '/tmp/ntplink':
  ensure  => link,
  target  => '/tmp/classtest',
  require => File['/tmp/classtest'],
}

file { '/tmp/classdir': ensure => directory }

exec { '/tmp/classtest':
  command => "mv /tmp/classtest /tmp/classdir",
  path    => '/bin/mv',
  require => File['/tmp/classtest'],
}

service { 'ntp-stop':
  ensure  => stopped,
  require => Service['ntp-run'],
}

package { 'ntp': ensure => absent }

file { '/tmp/classtest':
  ensure  => absent,
  require => Exec['/tmp/classtest'],
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: Package[ntp] is already declared in file /etc/puppet/ntp.pp:3; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/ntp.pp:34 on node ip-172-31-41-100.us-west-2.compute.internal
Error: Duplicate declaration: Package[ntp] is already declared in file /etc/puppet/ntp.pp:3; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/ntp.pp:34 on node ip-172-31-41-100.us-west-2.compute.internal
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have the same package managed on line 34 and on line 1.  Puppet is not a scripting language, but is a declarative language intended to model only the end state of a system's configuration.  What you're trying to do could be better accomplished using something like Ansible.